# Relabel values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a data frame of the form:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    "key": [100, 2000, 100, 5],
    "val": [1, 10, 2, 8]
})
```

I'd like to relabel `key` values into 0, 1, 2, ... that is:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    "key":  [100, 2000, 100, 5],
    "val":  [1, 10, 2, 8],
    "key2": [0, 1, 0, 2]
})
```

and know how to convert between `key` and `key2`, e.g. by a dictionary:

```
{
  100: 0,
  2000: 1,
  5: 2
}
```

I know that I could create manually a function creating a dictionary from `key` to `key2` and apply it to the `key` column, but I hope that there exists a *pandastic* approach.

Comment: `df['key2'] = df['key'].map(d)`

Comment: To me it looks like your `key` column is categorical, so [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) might be what you're looking for.